# Reliable and Free way to convert .docx, .doc, .rtf to PDF in .net

Tags: docx, pdf-conversion

The problem is, we dont have MS Office in our university anymore, earlier we used its
preview feature in Windows File Explorer, so to view multiple assignments on the fly by
just clicking on the word file or using arrow keys navigation. This helped us the teachers, to
check many assignments without having to open each file 1 by 1. Now we switched to WPS Office,
thus the preview feature in windows explorer is gone. This made the assignments checking extremely
slow as now we have to open each file before marking it.

I am a teacher too, who can code a little, so I want to build up an application in windows forms,
that enables to preview .docx, .dox and .rtf files. I tried hard since 1.5 months so far, used
Pandoc, OpenXML Powertools, tried with trial versions of libraries like Aspire, Aspose, GemBox, Xceeds

But so far no free and reliable solution is found, some of them either spoil the formatting in unacceptable way. Some of them have trial limits. Most of them do not convert word own drawings (that the students draw inside Word document itself).

So basically I am looking for a reliable and free resource that converts the whole document,
doesn't miss anything and is free. We the teachers, still can overlook formatting a little.

What I have tried: Everything as listed above, in win forms application

**Current best solution working for us:** Using Syncfusion DocIO library to convert the said file
formats to PDF and then loading that PDF in a CefSharp browser control in winforms. This requires
just ~2 seconds load time of the document and gives nice zooming options. But its a trial version
and eventually it will expire after trial period.

**NOTE:** I cannot use any online or server based solution as it will be very slow (consider clicking on the file and then waiting for more than 10 seconds to load a converted document).

Comment: @K J, we are using windows but WordPad does not allow previews in file explorer, also it cannot display Words's own drawings if we open file in wordpad. The problem is not with editing we are already using WPS Office which is fine for editing.

Comment: Yes I have in my mind, to use LibreOffice command line conversion in my WinForms app. That way I can run the CMD command without showing its interface (I already did that when using pandoc). So, if I dont get any better solution or trial version of Syncfusion creates any unavoidable issues, I will switch to LibreOffice CMD conversion. I will look at UnoConv now, thank you.